# Slice to get first occurrence if the values are in sequence in R

Tags: r

I am trying a situation where, I need to group Year values (number in format) and keep the first occurrence based on if they are in sequential format. Eg data:

| Org | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2011 | 1 |
| A | 2012 | 1 |
| A | 2013 | 2 |
| A | 2016 | 2 |
| A | 2017 | 2 |
| A | 2018 | 2 |
| A | 2019 | 2 |
| A | 2022 | 5 |
| B | 2007 | 1 |
| B | 2008 | 1 |
| B | 2009 | 1 |
| B | 2015 | 1 |
| B | 2016 | 1 |
| B | 2019 | 3 |
| B | 2021 | 4 |
| B | 2022 | 5 |

Expected Output:

| Org | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2011 | 1 |
| A | 2016 | 2 |
| A | 2022 | 5 |
| B | 2007 | 1 |
| B | 2015 | 1 |
| B | 2019 | 3 |
| B | 2021 | 4 |

Thank You!

Comment: look at `cgwtools` package, `seqle(`, an `rle` for sequences, very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text= "Org  Year    Value
A   2011    1
A   2012    1
A   2013    2
A   2016    2
A   2017    2
A   2018    2
A   2019    2
A   2022    5
B   2007    1
B   2008    1
B   2009    1
B   2015    1
B   2016    1
B   2019    3
B   2021    4
B   2022    5")

df |>
    filter(Org != lag(Org) | Year != lag(Year) + 1 | dplyr::row_number() == 1)
```